# What Does a Swift Data Type of "L" Stand For?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Within a `prepareForSegue()` function, I declared a constant as a ViewController type. When I access this constant, a value type with the character "L" appears next to it. I understand "M" stands for Method, "C" for class, and "V" stands variable, but what does this "L" stand for?

[image]

Aside: Not sure what "T" stands for either.

Comment: Local variable most likely

Comment: So as a local variable, does that mean it only exists within the function it's declared in?

Comment: hmm i retract my statement, doesnt seem to be the case

Comment: my detailViewController comes up as a V in my `prepareForSegue` odd, T seems to be a Typedef

Comment: Reopen: this answer covers Swift (and ObjC incidentally), the proposed duplicate only covers ObjC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the symbol for a **local variable**.

[image: screenshot]

You can see the differences in a playground:

[image] [image] [image]

Based on filenames alone, the other symbols are:

**B** — binding
**T** — builtin type, typedef
**c̱** — category
**C** — class, or class template
**C<sub>E</sub>** — class extension
**M** — method, method template, instance method, member
**V** — class variable, global variable, instance variable
**K** — const, enum constant
**E** — enum
**F** — field
**ƒ** — function, function template
**A** — IBAction method
**O** — IBOutlet, IBOutletCollection
**#** — macro
**C** (brown) — modeled class
**M** (brown) — modeled method
**P** (brown) — modeled property
**N** — namespace
**x** — parameter
**P** — property
**Pr** — protocol
**S** — struct
**U** — union

Comment: Actually as far as I can tell V is global variables.

Comment: V seems to be both global and instance. Added more screenshots.

Comment: it seems all variables in obj-c come out as V hence my confusion over the matter, only swift seems to make this differentiation, should of looked at the questions tags and the actual question derp. would of thought it would have been the same for both languages

Comment: Can you put the link for this folder please?

Comment: I don't know if the folder exists anymore. This was 6 years ago.