# What do the Xcode icons signify during autocompletion?

Tags: swift, xcode

See the `S`, `Pr`, `T`, `L` on the left side of the images - what do these initials signify? Kindly include answers for icons I have not mentioned here as well.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

I only know that `C` represents class and `S` represents Struct.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730359/what-does-a-swift-data-type-of-l-stand-for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Pr`otocol
`S`truct
`C`lass
`f`unction
`V`alue / `V`ariable
`T`ype
`L`ocal value / variable

Comment: L = Local variable

Comment: @robmayoff thanks!

Comment: I think you were right that T is typealias.

Comment: @robmayoff damn it, and it has already been asked and answered before anyway.

Comment: @luk2302 any way to add custom icons there ;)

Comment: You can add `M` = Method to this list and `{ }` for reserved keywords like `for`, `let`, `var` etc...

Comment: There is also  `I` for initializer

Comment: new version xcode, use **icon** to show, what's does mean symbol **#**

Answer (score 1):

As you've already surmised:

- C: class
- S: struct

Some others:

- Pr: Protocol
- Ex: extension (found in the symbol navigator, but not code completion)
- T: Type (generic type constraint, protocol associated type, etc)
- L: `let` constant / immutable property
- V: `var` variable / mutable property
- P: property (IIRC Xcode favors L/V for Swift, but you see P for ObjC properties)

(Not 100% sure of the last three, and I'm on the phone so I can't check. Will follow up later to verify those and add some more...)